# emacs ff-find-other-file and ff-search-directories isn't recursive

Tags: search, emacs, recursion, directory, subdirectory

Can we make ff-find-other-file to search recursively in directories which are listed in ff-search-directories.

Instead of searching only in /usr/include, it would also search in /usr/include/llvm. Or likewise.

Answer (score 3):

I've added this function to my `.emacs` file:

```
(defun get-all-subdirectories(dir-list)
  "Returns a list of all recursive subdirectories of dir-list, 
   ignoring directories with names that start with . (dot)"
  (split-string 
   (shell-command-to-string 
     (concat "find " 
             (mapconcat 'identity dir-list " ")
             " -type d -not -regex \".*/\\\..*\""))))
```

And, in my `c-mode-common-hook`, I have this:

```
(setq ff-search-directories (get-all-subdirectories (list "dirA" "dirB")))
```

This assumes you have a standard Unix `find` command in your `PATH`.  If you're on Windows, you can get a copy of `find` here: http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

It takes a little while to run if you have many directories for it to recurse through.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `/*` after the directories where you want subdirectories searched. So set `ff-search-directories` so that it contains `"/usr/include/*"`.

Comment: I don't believe that's recursive.

Comment: I'm probably doing it wrong. But I think I've used the wildcard *star method  in my .emacs file. That doesn't do anything. Only when I set the specific c++ subdirectory of includes would it ff-find-other-file iostream and likewise for llvm libraries.

Comment: Michael is correct, `*` wildcard is recursive in `ff-search-directories`.

Comment: @MartinÜnsal : somehow it doesn't behave recursively for me either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990197/emacs-ff-find-other-file-does-not-find-my-header