# Smarter `ff-find-other-file`

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm working on a project where the source is organised in the following directory structe:

```
./source/include
./source/include/analysis
./source/include/tools
./source/include/utils
./source/include/utils/stream
./source/include/utils/string
[...]
./source/src
./source/src/analysis
./source/src/tools
./source/src/utils
./source/src/utils/stream
./source/src/utils/string
[...]
```

Where each subdirectory of `./source/include/` (including `./source/include/`) contains header files. Similarly every subdir of `./source/src/` (including `./source/src/`) contains implementation files.

When using `ff-find-other-file` on files which reside at the "top-level" (i.e. in `./source/include`/ or `./source/src/`) everything works fine. However I can't figure out how one can configure `ff-search-directories` to search deeper up and back into the directory tree.

There's already a question on SO ([emacs ff-find-other-file and ff-search-directories isn't recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983493/emacs-ff-find-other-file-and-ff-search-directories-isnt-recursive)) but it does not solve my problem since this works only with a static setup.

An ideal solution would be something like this (pseudo-regexp solution, where `DIR_REGEXP` matches all possible directory names):

```lisp
"../\(DIR_REGEXP\)/include/\1/"
"../\(DIR_REGEXP\)/\(DIR_REGEXP\)/include/\1/\2/"
```

Is there any elisp snippet/package out there which can provide a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commentary is pretty comprehensive, I think:

`M-x find-library RET find-file RET`

The example given for `ff-search-directories` is:

```
;; SEARCHING is carried out in a set of directories specified by the
;; ff-search-directories variable:
;;
;;     ("." "../../src" "../include/*" "/usr/local/*/src/*" "$PROJECT/src")
;;
;; This means that the corresponding file will be searched for first in
;; the current directory, then in ../../src, then in one of the directories
;; under ../include, and so on. The star is _not_ a general wildcard
;; character: it just indicates that the subdirectories of this directory
;; must each be searched in turn. Environment variables will be expanded in
;; the ff-search-directories variable.
```

If that's insufficient, `ff-other-file-alist` can contain function symbols which can act dynamically to "return a list consisting of the possible names of the corresponding file". See the usage of `ff-cc-hh-converter` (which is defined in the library as a reference).

Comment: Somehow I missed this... I got it working using one/multiple wildcards. However, this'll probably increase search-time since it must search all subdirectories.