# emacs ff-find-other-file does not find my header

Tags: emacs

Somehow I can't make emacs' `ff-find-other-file` to get my header file. Here is what I have (minimal example):

```
cd ~/tmp
mkdir test
cd test
mkdir -p src/a/b inc/a/b
echo "aaaa" > src/a/b/a.cpp
echo "bbbb" > inc/a/b/a.hpp
tree
```

gives:

```
.
├── inc
│   └── a
│       └── b
│           └── a.hpp
└── src
    └── a
        └── b
            └── a.cpp
```

This is similar to my project structure.

---

```
emacs -Q src/a/b/a.cpp
```

Then copying this in `*scratch*` and executing it with `C-x C-e`:

```
(setq cc-search-directories '("." "../inc" "../inc/*" "../../inc/*" "../../../inc/*" "/usr/include"))
```

and running `ff-find-other-file` in buffer `a.cpp`, only results in a prompt in the minibuffer:

> `Find or create a.hpp in: ~/tmp/test/src/a/b/`

`C-h v` on `ff-search-directories` returns `cc-search-directories`, and on `cc-search-directories` I get the list above.

I expect `ff-find-other-file` to look in `../../../inc/*`, and find `a.hpp`. Why doesn't it?

---

**Edit**: it seems to be the recursive part that doesn't work here.

After:

```
cp inc/a/b/a.hpp inc/
```

`a.hpp` is found from `a.cpp`.

The help about `ff-search-directories` says:

> The stars are *not* wildcards: they are searched for together with
>   the preceding slash.  The star represents all the subdirectories except
>   `..', and each of these subdirectories will be searched in turn.

Note that this quote if from the help for `ff-search-directories`, while the list I modified is `cc-search-directories`. I can't see why that would make a difference though.

This and other threads on SO made me believe `*` would recursively search the directory tree. Wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` represents every immediate sub-directory of its parent; nothing more.

The commentary has it worded slightly more clearly:

> The star is *not* a general wildcard character: it just indicates that the subdirectories of this directory must each be searched in turn.

i.e. For this specific example I would expect `"../../../inc/*/b"` to work. Or indeed `"../../../inc/*/*"` (as you've ended up using).

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/23662870/324105 and note in particular that you can define functions to dynamically generate the target file path(s).

I suspect you want the `a/b` to be determined based on the original path, so a function to return the appropriate path to the other file would be your best solution here.

Answer (score 2):

Another options is to use **Projectile** and execute the `projectile-find-other-file` command. Since projectile knows about your project structure, it will match your cpp/h files automatically. It is a little slower than ff-find-other-file, but it seems to do the job pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, the search turns out not to be recursive after all. These other questions and answers here made me misread the help (quoted in the question).

"Each of these subdirectories will be searched in turn", does not imply that *their* subdirectories also will be searched.

Since the depth of my tree is limited, I just modified my `cc-search-directories`:

```
(setq cc-search-directories '("."
                              "../inc" "../inc/*" "../../inc/*" "../../../inc/*"
                              "../../inc/*/*" "../../../inc/*/*/*"
                              "../src" "../src/*" "../../src/*" "../../../src/*"
                              "../../src/*/*" "../../../src/*/*/*"
                              "/usr/include" "/usr/local/include/*"))
```

Comment: I discovered the multiple asterisk way as well, but found that merely one `inc/*/*/*/*` worked on all 4 levels, no need to have one entry for each permutation